# How to embed special markers into the code listing that will mark certain parts of code to be colored using a custom scheme?

Tags: listings, color

I would like to color my C# code listings as Visual Studio does. However, all language definitions that I found so far only color the keywords and not the user types. I understand that it requires parsing the code and may not be supported by the listings package, therefore I am ready to specify the color of each word myself. E.g. something like this:

```
\definecolor{usertype}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C#]
public interface {\color{usertype}IEntity}
{
  {\color{usertype}Guid} Guid { get; }
  {\color{usertype}ICollection}<{\color{usertype}IComponent}> Components { get; }
  {\color{usertype}IComponent} this[string componentName] { get; }
  event {\color{usertype}EventHandler}<{\color{usertype}ComponentEventArgs}> CreatedComponent;
  event {\color{usertype}EventHandler}<{\color{usertype}ChangedAttributeEventArgs}> ChangedAttribute;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Note that some entries such as `Guid` are used both as a type and as an identifier. Unfortunately, this doesn't work as entries like `{\color{usertype}...}` are literally written into the output. How can I specify the color of individual words or code pieces in a listing? Or is there a better package than `lstlisting` for this?

**UPDATE:** I have tried using `\texttt`, but it ignores the spaces in the beginning of the line, requires `\\` at the end of each line to force a line break and characters such as `{` and `}` must be escaped as `\{` and `\}`.

Even better would be if I could mark certain words as belonging to a specific class via some special symbol, e.g. like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C#]
public interface @IEntity
{
  @Guid Guid { get; }
  @ICollection<@IComponent> Components { get; }
  @IComponent this[string componentName] { get; }
  event @EventHandler<@ComponentEventArgs> CreatedComponent;
  event @EventHandler<@ChangedAttributeEventArgs> ChangedAttribute;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Tried using `minted` package. It parses the code and thus is able to highlight it better, but still doesn't highlight the user types.

Comment: You don't need to mark up every token separately: You can extend the type definitions with your own keywords. But the definitions are at the token level, i.e., you can't straightforwardly color the same word twice depending on context. So for this (and only for this) you need some work-around.

Comment: I posted and answer and Jubobs correctly mentioned the problem with words that are both datatypes and identifiers. If you find my answer not suitable for you problem please let me know. Meanwhile you can have a look at [**this**](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) link. Minted uses python pygments thus, you can write you own lexer.

Comment: @Pouya Writing a lexer will be way more work than just manually coloring pieces that I need. I don't see your answer. Did you delete it?

Answer (score 5):

### Only if you're on suicide watch...

Your sample code here is relatively short, so you could perform ad-hoc syntax highlighting, if you find the courage in you. However, as the length of the code increases, modifying the listing manually just to get the desired syntax highlighting becomes more and more of a pain. Imagine if you had, not merely a short sample code in a `.tex` file, but lots and lots of source files; you would kill yourself if you had to modify every single one of them just so they get typeset as desired when imported into a LaTeX document.

Fortunately, you can delegate a lot of that repetitive stuff to `listings`. It has limited lexing capabilities, but you can still come up with workarounds that make your life easier.

### A solution with some automation

My understanding is that you want to get the desired syntax highlighting of of the word `Guid`, which can be, depending on the context, either a *type* or an *identifier*. If you don't use any dirty trick, `listings` is just going to use the same style for each occurence of a given "word". However you can make `listings` context-aware by implementing a simple finite state machine; here is one possibility using a switch and `listings`'s `emph` and `\emphstyle` keys.

Define `Guid` as a special identifier class (`emph=[2]{Guid}`), and use a finite state machine consisting only of one Boolean state, the `\ifGuidAlreadyUsed` switch. The latter is used to keep track of whether `Guid` has already occured on the current line. The `\ProcessGuid` macro then hightlights the first occurence of `Guid` on each line, but not later occurences of `Guid` on that line (if any).

That should produce the desired syntax highlighting you want, under the following assumption: **there are no multiple occurences of `Guid` *type* on the same line**.

Furthermore, if

1. there are other "words" that can be either a *type* or an *identifier* in your code,
2. you happen to have a list of those words handy, and
3. that list is not too long,

then you can extend the strategy explained above to those words without too much effort.

**Note**: to select the predefined language corresponding to `C#`, you need to to pass the value `[Sharp]C` to the `language` key; if you pass `C#`, you'll get an error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{usertype}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68} 

\makeatletter
\lstdefinestyle{SergiyCsharp}       % define custom style
{
    language = [Sharp]C,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    emph =[1]                                               % basic user types
    {
        ChangedAttributeEventArgs,
        ComponentEventArgs,
        EventHandler,
        ICollection,
        IComponent,
        IEntity,
    },
    emphstyle =[1]\color{usertype},
    emph =[2]{Guid},                                % Guid user type
    emphstyle =[2]\ProcessGuid,
}

% Boolean state of a state machine dedicated to keep track of whether
% Guid has already occured on the current line or not
\newif\ifGuidAlreadyUsed
\GuidAlreadyUsedfalse       % initialised as false

% Highlight Guid if it is the first occurence on the current line;
% Do not highlight it otherwise.
\newcommand\ProcessGuid
{%
    \ifGuidAlreadyUsed%
    \else%
        \global\GuidAlreadyUsedtrue%
        \color{usertype}%
    \fi%
}

% At the end of each line, reset the state to false
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\global\GuidAlreadyUsedfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=SergiyCsharp]
public interface IEntity
{
  Guid Guid { get; }
  ICollection<IComponent> Components { get; }
  IComponent this[string componentName] { get; }
  event EventHandler<ComponentEventArgs> CreatedComponent;
  event EventHandler<ChangedAttributeEventArgs> ChangedAttribute;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort you took to write this answer. Indeed this is a nice solution. However, I was looking more at the "suicide watch" section. There will be at most 2-3 pages of code in my work, so that's not the issue to manually color it. Can you please explain how to do this on a short example? In other words - how can I embed special markers into the source code that will allow me to color parts of the code in some custom style.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov That sounds totally unmaintainable. I'm afraid I don't have the courage to post such a solution...

Comment: It may be unmaintainable, but it is a solution, which will fit into my limited time frame that I have to finish my thesis :-). If you don't feel the courage to post it here, please write it to my email address: rryk [at] gmail [dot] com. Although if you post it here, I am sure other people will appreciate this until a better solution is created by someone who has more time.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov You must be kidding. That's not how this site works...

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov Sorry, but if you have 3 pages of code that you need to adjust, and you need it quick, then I'm sure the fastest solution is to do it manually. You can start with what `minted` outputs as an auxiliary file.

Comment: @tohecz That's a great idea. In fact it answers my question. Thanks.