# Conditional syntax highlighting for the same function, possibly using delimiters

Tags: minted

Is there any way to conditionally highlight syntaxes in `minted`?

I have the same name for an argument of a function as well as a function itself, messing up the syntax highlighting pretty badly.

A workaround is to differentiate between `<function> =` and `<function>(` in their totalities, but this would apply the colour to the equals sign and brace respectively, leading to a pretty ugly output.

Is it possible to still only colour the `<function>` part, using the equals to sign (`=`) or brace (`)`) only as a delimiter, but keeping the colour scheme (for these signs) intact?

Comment: `minted` relies on Pygments lexers, which are written in Python. I'm not sure (because you don't specify which `minted` language you're using) but I'd be tempted to say that the answer is no. However, even if that's not possible with `minted`, it should be possible with `listings`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153819/how-to-embed-special-markers-into-the-code-listing-that-will-mark-certain-parts/153828#153828

Comment: Elegant solution, I'm already using `listings` as compatibility alternative to `minted` (printing everything in `minted` takes around a minute and I'm running a serious PC here), but `listings` doesn't handle functions with dots inside them very well like `file.choose` or `read.table`. Heh, everything has pros and cons.

Comment: Whatever output you want to produce is likely feasible with `listings`. You should edit your question to add a MWE and specify exactly what you want to achieve. About `minted` being slow, note that the new maintainer is working on making it way faster.

Comment: Without additional details (e.g. the Pygments lexer used or some compilable code), I think that this question remains unclear.