# listing with color and strike-through remaks

Tags: color, listings

I want to show a code listing with some block in green (code additions) and other ones in red and strike-through (code removed).

This is what I have until now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\add}{\makebox[0pt]{\color{green}\rule[-1ex]{\paperwidth}{4ex}}}
\newcommand{\del}{\makebox[0pt]{\color{red}\rule[-1ex]{\paperwidth}{4ex}}}

\lstset{ %
  language=Python,                       % the language of the code
  escapechar=|
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):

         x = 0

|\add|        x = 11
|\add|        x = 12

|\del|        x = 21
|\del|        x = 22

        x = 40
        x = 41


\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

that gives following result:

[image]

with this approach, no way found to do the strikethrough.

Using `moredelim` instead of `escapechar` in listing config:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\add}[1]{\colorbox{green}{\strut#1}}
\newcommand{\del}[1]{\colorbox{red}{\strut\sout{#1}}}

\lstset{ %
  language=Python,                       % the language of the code
  moredelim    = [is][\add]{>+>}{<+<},
  moredelim    = [is][\del]{>->}{<-<}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):

         x = 0

>+>        x = 11<+<

>->        x = 21<-<

        x = 40
        x = 41


\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

gives following result:

[image]

where the strike is broken in words instead of continuous (and green/red background doesn't fills all line).

Any suggestion to obtain first result (or similar) with the strike-through?

(note: marks `|\add|`, `>+>`, ..., are automatically generated by a "diff" program. It is possible to modify them, but always in a line-by-line basis or code blocks for each addition or removal of consecutive statements).

Comment: This question seems to be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288857/displaying-source-code-listing-with-strikethrough-strikeout . However, it is not fully a duplicate.